# Eclipse shortcut to accept type proposal with appended same-name lowercase starting variable

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-rcp, code-completion

Is there a way, to create a attribute/method parameter/local variable by type, with same name as type starting with lowercase letter?

Example:

1. `Redi` [ctrl+space], and "`RedirectAttributes`" type is proposed
2. [magic shortcut]
3. IDE inserts: `RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes`

If not, where should I start to implement such code completion plugin?

Comment: Just press Ctrl+Space again after inserting the type and that name will be one of the suggestions.

Comment: I know, but I'm doing this so often that it would be cool to improve this even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+space` after the type is added.

```
PrintWriter -> Ctrl+space proposes printWriter
```

If a different shortcut is needed, then you would have to implement it. [This link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F) explains how to provide a custom keyboard shortcut.